# Returning anonymous JS function which returns javascript plain object from Dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

**Dart Code**

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'package:js/js.dart';

void main() {

  var data = new AddLocationData(locationName: "Location1", locationPath: "ThisFolder");
  var func = () => data;
  html.window.console.log(func);
  html.window.console.log(func());
}

@JS("")
@anonymous
class AddLocationData {
  external String get locationName;
  external String get locationPath;
  external factory AddLocationData({String locationName, String locationPath});
}
```

You would assume that `func` will be a js function but its not. Its type/name is `main_closure`. See the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

So the first two lines were printed from Dart code then I used Chrome Inspect Element window and right clicked on `main_closure' and selected "Store as global variable" which then printed`temp1` and then I used it to display some information about the generated code.

So it is clear Dart returned an object and not a js function and so is the reason of asking this question.

So I want `temp1` to be a function instead of `temp1.call$0` so that I can get the data by calling `temp1()` and not `temp1.call$0()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [js package doc](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js):

> Passing functions to JavaScript.
>
> If you are passing a Dart function to a JavaScript API, you must wrap it using `allowInterop` or `allowInteropCaptureThis`.

Comment: Thanks.`var func = js.allowInterop(() => data);` fixed the issue :D